# Run an RSpec example with exception-raising code without raise_error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

To test whether code raises an exception using RSpec, you can use a block with `raise_error`:

```
it "raises an exception" do
  expect { raise_an_exception }.to raise_error
end
```

Let's say you want to test whether the code that raises an exception does something else as well. Must you always use the above syntax?

```
# testing whether an error is raised
it "reraises exceptions" do
  expect { log_exception_and_reraise }.to raise_error(ExceptionClass)
end

# not testing whether an error is raised
it "logs errors" do
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error)
  expect { log_exception_and_reraise }.to raise_error
end

# not testing whether an error is raised
it "sends errors to error tracker"
  expect(ErrorTracker).to receive(:send_error)
  expect { log_exception_and_reraise }.to raise_error
end
```

This works, but you're testing two separate things in each example (even though you don't want to). And you have to duplicate the `raise_error` expectation for each one.

I'd rather do something like

```
it "sends errors to error tracker"
  expect(ErrorTracker).to receive(:send_error)
  execute { log_exception_and_reraise }
end
```

Comment: Is your question about whether you have to pass a code block to `expect` if you are expecting to raise an error? If so, then yes, it has to be a code block for RSpec to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with how you wrote it. If you do not want to test multiple assertions in the same test, then you can split them, but if the test triggers an exception, you have to expect it.

Was that what you asked?

Btw, it is a bad practice to just raise_error. Its much better to pass it the correct class of exception that you expect, for example:

```
expect { log_exception_and_reraise }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```